# Wordpress Learnpress filter to modify levels

Tags: php, wordpress, learnpress

I'm trying to add more choices in the levels field of Wordpress LearnPress plugin via the filters, but my code doesn't work.

On the LearnPress plugin in the folder *inc* we have the file *lp-template-functions.php* starting on line 1709

```
/**
 * Get level post meta.
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 *
 * @return string
 */
function learn_press_get_post_level( $post_id ) {
    $level = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_lp_level', true );

    return apply_filters(
        'learn-press/level-label',
        ! empty( $level ) ? lp_course_level()[ $level ] : esc_html__( 'All levels', 'learnpress' ),
        $post_id
    );
}

function lp_course_level() {
    return apply_filters(
        'lp/template/function/course/level',
        array(
            ''             => esc_html__( 'All levels', 'learnpress' ),
            'beginner'     => esc_html__( 'Beginner', 'learnpress' ),
            'intermediate' => esc_html__( 'Intermediate', 'learnpress' ),
            'expert'       => esc_html__( 'Expert', 'learnpress' ),
        )
    );
}
```

In my *functions.php* I added the following filters but it doesn't work

```
//CHANGE LEVELS FROM LP-TEMPLATE-FUNCTIONS
add_filter('learn-press/level-label', 'modify_course_level');
       function modify_course_level($level){
       $level['beginner'] = esc_html__("1ere année primaire", "learnpress");
       $level['intermediate'] = esc_html__("2e année primaire","learnpress");
       $level['expert'] = esc_html__("3e année primaire", "learnpress");
       return $level;
   }
// ADD LEVELS 
add_filter('learn-press/level-label', 'add_extra_course_level');
function add_extra_course_level($level){
   $level['extra-level-1'] = esc_html__("4e année primaire", "learnpress");
   $level['extra-level-2'] = esc_html__("5e année primaire", "learnpress");
   return $level;
}
```

I expected the level difficulty dropdown to change, but still showing the original choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I named the filter wrong, instead of `add_filter('learn-press/level-label'),` it's `add_filter('lp/template/function/course/level'),` here is the working code:

```
//CHANGE LEVELS FROM LP-TEMPLATE-FUNCTIONS
add_filter('lp/template/function/course/level', 'modify_course_level');
       function modify_course_level($level){
       $level['beginner'] = "1ere année primaire";
       $level['intermediate'] = "2e année primaire";
       $level['expert'] = "3e année primaire";
       return $level;
   }
//ADD LEVELS 
add_filter('lp/template/function/course/level', 'add_extra_course_level');
if ( ! function_exists('add_extra_course_level')){
function add_extra_course_level($level){
   $level['extra-level-1'] = "4e année primaire";
   $level['extra-level-2'] = "5e année primaire";
   return $level;
   }
}
```